# D3 js tree in angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I want add d3 js tree in my angular app and add to app component with certain data.i have confused how to do configure with my angular app.please,help me how to do that

Comment: Google and you can find lot of tutorials.!

Answer (score 0):

**Step -1** : `npm install d3 angular-d3-tree --save`

**Step -2 : In your app.module.ts file**

```
import { AngularD3TreeLibModule } from 'angular-d3-tree';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
       AngularD3TreeLibModule,
       // Other Modules
   ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step -3: In app.component.html**

```
<s2w-angular-d3-tree-lib
  [(treeData)]="data"
  (onNodeChanged)="nodeUpdated($event)"
  (onNodeSelected)="nodeSelected($event)"></s2w-angular-d3-tree-lib>
```

**Step -4: In app.component.ts**

```
import { AngularD3TreeLibService } from 'angular-d3-tree';

export class MyComponent {
  data: any[];

  constructor(private treeService: AngularD3TreeLibService) {
    this.data= YOUR_DATA;
  }
  nodeUpdated(node:any){
    console.info("app detected node change");
  }
  nodeSelected(node:any){
    console.info("app detected node selected", node);
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting error 'AngularD3TreeLibModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class which trying to importin my app.module.ts file