# 'AngularD3TreeLibModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am following the below references for creating a collapsible tree in my angular application.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-tree-m6imfc?file=README.md

[D3 js tree in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967773/d3-js-tree-in-angular)

While adding Angular D3TreeLibModule to the imports array of my app.module.ts file, I get the following error:

'AngularD3TreeLibModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
angular-d3-tree-lib.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (angular-d3-tree) which declares AngularD3TreeLibModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Also using the  tag gives an error which I assume is part of the import issue.

PS: I am trying to recreate something like https://jsoncrack.com/editor.